# Porque el componente de react-select se sobrepone sobre otros componentes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

Buenas tengo un problema al utilizar las librerias de react-select y el componente textfield de material-ui alguien sabe que podria ser?

Asi se ve los componentes cuando esta una opcion seleccionada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando se desplega se ve asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando redux-form asi que los componentes se renderizan con el componente field

Si alguien sabe la respuesta se lo agradeceria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe una propiedad llamada [`z-index`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) que controla la sobreposicion de un elemento sobre otro elemento. Lo mas probable es que el elemento que contiene el texto **Fecha de inicio *** tenga un `z-index` mayor al elemento del `react-select`.

Por ejemplo:

```css
#padre
{
  position:absolute;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
}

#hijo
{
  position:absolute;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  left:25px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="padre"></div>
  <div id="hijo"></div>
</div>
```

Por defecto todos los elementos tienen un `z-index:0`. Nota como hijo esta sobre el padre, pero si queremos que sea al reves, le indicamos un `z-index` mas alto al padre para que aparezca arriba del hijo:

```css
#padre
{
  position:absolute;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
  z-index:2; <= le asignamos un z-index mayor
}

#hijo
{
  position:absolute;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  left:25px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="padre"></div>
  <div id="hijo"></div>
</div>
```

En resumen, intenta asignarle al texto un z-index menor. Sino te funciona, sigue intentando con otro menor hasta que apareza debajo.

Comment: En efecto esa propiedad soluciono el problema, estoy agradecido.